# my app is not working and keeps stopping. How can I fix this?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, navigation, fragment

My app is not working and keeps stopping. How can I fix this issue?
This is my first fragment code.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_start1, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    start2BT.setOnClickListener {
        Navigation.findNavController(it).navigate(Start1FragmentDirections.actionStart1ToStart2())
    }
}
```

When I run my app this happens.
[error message!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYbSk.jpg)
I hope you understand where the problem is.

I don't know where the problem is from.

Comment: You should include the error you get in the logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to post the log cat error.
but from your class, I found that you didn't define and initialize the view but you are calling an onClick listener on it.
i mean this line:

```
 start2BT.setOnClickListener {
        Navigation.findNavController(it).navigate(Start1FragmentDirections.actionStart1ToStart2())
    }
```

you need to have something like this before that line

```
var start2BT = (Button)view.findViewByID(R.id.start2BT)
```

keep in mind that this was for a button.
you can define and initialize the button on the `onCreateView` and also change

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_start1, container, false)
```

to this

```
var view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_start1, container, false)
return view
```